# Textile question: redcloth anchor links

Tags: ruby-on-rails, markup, textile, redcloth

How do I write this in textile (i'm using the redcloth gem)

```
<a href="#tips">Visit the Useful Tips Section</a>
<a name="tips">Useful Tips Section</a>
```

I know the first part, `"Visit the Useful Tips Section":#tips` but how do I make the named anchor?

Thanks!

Deb

Comment: h1(#tips) Useful Tips Section. -- Achieves the same effect (with some css) but doesn't really answer the question.

Comment: thanks Noel, that's good enough for me :)

Comment: hi noel, do you want to add your comment as an answer so I can accept it? :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

h1(#tips) Useful Tips Section. -- Achieves the same effect (with some css)

Answer (score 2):

The [textile manual](http://redcloth.org/textile) seems to indicate that there's no way to do so other than just using straight HTML:

```
<a name="tips"></a>
<h1>Useful Tips Section</h1>
```

The answer that suggests:

```
h1(#tips). Useful Tips Section
```

is incorrect as it will generate:

```
<h1 id="tips">Useful Tips Section</h1>
```

which is not a named anchor.  However, you could use some Javascript to make this work.

Comment: i think you need to enclose this in a notextile declaration:          <notextile><a name="tips"></a></notextile>